# Facebook Connect Error

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I am trying to integrate the Facebook connect for signup as well as for login to the website. The steps has been followed correctly to integrate the Facebook plugin, but whenever the Facebook button is clicked on the signup or registration form, it gives an message " An error occurred. Please try again later."

The link to signup and login form where the FB connect is being used are as follows:

Login : http://testing.seishindo.org/amember/member/index

The same error goes for the signup form to.
I have entered the following details while creating the FB application:

Display Name: Seishindo
App domain: Seishindo.org
category : others
Select how your app integrates with Facebook

Website: site URL: http://testing.seishindo.org/amember/

Can you suggest which step I have missed, Every time i click on the FB connect button I get error message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for that error message is that the domain in the Facebook App configuration and the actual used one do not match.

Check that you really specified http://testing.seishindo.org as website in the app configuration.

Comment: Hello Hendrik,I have specified http://testing.seishindo.org as website in the app configuration, but still I am getting this error. Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up on this page. If you are really sure you correctly entered the domain details, make sure your app is not in sandbox mode. That was my mistake. You can turn it of in settings->basic.